# unable to install npm packages in created folder - ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, yarnpkg

The system I am using is Ubuntu 17. 
I cloned a repository from github in the bundler-app folder.
I created a folder packages in it using `mkdir packages/myfolder`.
Now, I go to the `myfolder` folder and do `yarn add react react-dom`
and the install happens.  Everything seems to go smoothly and yet
when I go to the `myfolder` folder and see what's in there... it's empty.

There's nothing in it.

So, where did the yarn/npm packages go?

Answer (score 0):

Does one of the parent folders of `myfolder` contains a `package.json`, if so yarn adds the package there.

If you need different behaviour to install under the current folder, even if a parent folder has `package.json`, you will have to make sure current folder has a `package.json`, which can be done via `yarn init`.

So in your case you can try

`yarn init` then `yarn add react react-dom` inside the folder and you will find the package in the folder